# Why does localforage throw "UnknownError" in Firefox ESR?

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb, localforage

In Firefox ESR (45.4.0) localforage throws an `UnknownError` upon the *first* `getItem`, `setItem` or `clear` statement. But only the first, no matter how much time passes until it happens. The value gets read/written properly though.

Can anyone explain, why this happens in Firefox ESR, but neither in "normal" Firefox, Chrome or Safari?

Take the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/localforage/1.4.3/localforage.js"></script>
    <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        localforage.setItem("foo", 123)
        .then(function (value) { console.log("value = " + value); }) //value = 123
        .catch(function (err) { console.error("error: " + err); });
    }, 2000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

Console output:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

From localForage's bug tracker, where this issue [has been reported](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/335):

> Firefox does not allow to access to IndexedDB / Localstorage if the browser is in private mode.

Comment: If by "private mode" they mean incognito mode, I'm not using that.

Comment: @jaySon Chrome has "incognito mode", Firefox has "private browsing". I can only assume Firefox ESR uses private browsing by default.

Comment: @jaySon it may be worth trying to use the native `localStorage` and checking to see if any errors are given. In your console, enter: `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")`.

Comment: Nope, `localStorage` is doing just fine. But localforage is not writing into the localStorage. I can't even force it to use localStorage as driver, but probably I'm misunderstandig something when it comes to localforage drivers ...

Comment: @jaySon in that case I suggest you submit a [new issue](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/new) on localForage's bug tracker, referencing that other issue and explaining why that doesn't apply in your situation.